# Alternatives to deprecated classes OpenDaylight

Tags: java, deprecated, opendaylight

Which alternatives to the following deprecated classes should I use?

```
org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeConnector
org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeConnectorId
org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeConnectorRef
org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeId
org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.inventory.rev130819.NodeRef
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole inventory model is deprecated in favor of network topology, I2RS and similar. Network topology seems to be current industry standard.
OpenDaylight ships the 2013 model revision - see https://github.com/opendaylight/mdsal/blob/master/model/ietf/ietf-topology/src/main/yang/network-topology%402013-10-21.yang